# Thread refuses to quit

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm experiencing a problem with `QThread::currentThread()->quit();`

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include "myobject.h"

QThread* cThread;
MyObject* cObject;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    cThread = new QThread();
    cObject = new MyObject();
    cObject->moveToThread(cThread);

    QObject::connect(cThread, SIGNAL(started()),
                     cObject, SLOT(doWork()));

    QObject::connect(cThread, SIGNAL(finished()),
                     cThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    QObject::connect(cThread, SIGNAL(finished()),
                     cObject, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    cThread->start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

myobject.cpp:

```
#include "myobject.h"

MyObject::MyObject(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void MyObject::doWork()
{
    qDebug() << "Hi";
    QThread::currentThread()->quit(); // It is supposed to stop here, but it doesn't.
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        qDebug() << i;
    }
}
```

myobject.h:

```
#ifndef MYOBJECT_H
#define MYOBJECT_H

#include <QtCore>

class MyObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyObject(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
    void doWork();

};

#endif // MYOBJECT_H
```

It is supposed to stop in myobject.cpp with `QThread::currentThread()->quit();` but it doesn't.

Getting an error saying that this question is too short.

Solution: add "return;" after the quit call.

Comment: Even if the event loop is quit correctly, that won't prevent execution of the for loop after the quit() call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation of the function exit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#exit) (which is what quit calls):

> Note that unlike the C library function of the same name, this
>   function does return to the caller -- it is event processing that
>   stops

Which means the code you wrote is behaving as it should by going into the loop. You are stopping the event loop of the thread from executing, and that's the only thing *quit* does. The thread will finish the execution of `doWork()`.

Now it raises an interesting question : will `cThread` and `cObject` be deleted? No. An object with *deleteLater* will be deleted when [the control returns to the event loop](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#deleteLater). But here you just stopped the event loop of the thread, so even if the *deleteLater* are posted  they will not be processed.

Your object will survive and you will have a memory leak. An easy test will be to declare a dummy destructor for `MyObject` which just prints something and check if it is called.

Comment: Hmm... Any ideas to fix the memory leak? I guess I would have to return to the event loop and then call quit? But the issue is that I don't have access to the event loop.

Comment: Qt handles `deleteLater()` correctly and does not create a memory leak.  If you subclass `QThread`, and observe its `deleteLater()` call with `void deleteLater()
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
        QThread::deleteLater();
    }` you will see it gets called before the program exits.

Answer (score 0):

The [quit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#quit) function only will terminate the event loop associated with the thread if you have one.

By default the [run](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#run) method calls the [exec](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#exec) method that starts the event loop.

Seeing the the code of the QThread:

```
emit started
run();
```

This means that when the *started* event is emitted your event loop was not started yet because it will only be started inside of the run method. The method *quit* will only work if the event loop is already started with the *exec* call.

I hope this can help

Comment: Yes, you are correct I saw the code the a bad way. I will fix my answer.